# How can i realize that I'm stuck on Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, server, middleware

I'm Using Express with NodeJS.
I've tried to send a req to my localhost:3000, but seems like there's an Error becouse the page keep loading forever..
After 'racking my brain', I realized that I have'nt use next() at the end of app.use() middleware.

**Is there any better way i can realize that i'm stuck on certain middleware instead of reading the whole middlewares and look for any miss next() function ?**
I mean, when the page got stuck, how can i realize that this is a missing next() error, if there's no error message.

Comment: Opinionated Comment: In the entire app, you most probably only have max 4-5 custom middlewares. 4-5 next() shouldn't be too difficult to track and debug since it's a one-time thing. You more likely will end up with no response error because you forget to use `res`

Comment: If only for debugging purposes, I always try to `console.log('reached this line')` in my APIs if I can't figure where the error occurs so if you can't even reach the first line you know it's either a frontend or a middleware error